# How do I find commits in Git that weren't included in a merge or pull request?

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request

I'm using Git fronted by GitLab.

Most of the code changes are done through merge requests (similar to pull requests in GitHub), where another developer reviews the changes and accepts the request to merge the commits into the main branch from some other branch.

Occasionally developers will push directly to the main branch without going through merge requests. We'd like to retroactively review those commits. Is it possible to run a git command to list any direct push commits that weren't a part of a merge request?

Answer (score 1):

On your own local copy of the repo, you could remember where the `master` branch has got up to by creating a temporary branch off of it:

```
git checkout -b master prev_master
```

Then fetch the updated master branch from the remote, e.g.

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master master
```

Then you can examine the log of all the more recent changes:

```
git log --raw prev_master..master
```

(I like to use “`--raw`” because it shows which files have changed.) Does that sound like what you’re after?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is currently like what I'm doing now: review the commits manually verifying they were included in merge requests. I was just hoping someone had figured out a way to automate the check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the use case is different, but I use `git cherry` to find unmerged commits.

So, for example, you can run `git cherry -v master staging` and this will list all commits that are on staging but not on master.

The output will look like this

```
+ 30ad3d54a0e7b3b4127e5d6c214589e55c13951c Fix popup ui
+ d3ada650177eda21195e8694c83c9b6a03757a05 Fixed jenkins errors
+ 07f35ad04d9e9352b8693a9a59c5a369d17f2576 Fixed select box functionality
+ 60f9ae2d3ff9f7dbc5eda2cf57adcb86c7b16522 integrated API with frontend and replaced the dummy date used for temp purpose
+ 4a7309f5af06fffc1ba154c48fd9e5c60b9d3d8d Preview drop down added
```

You can find more details in the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry):

Do not confuse this with `git cherry-pick` which is a very different command.